# Can I call OfflineContext's startRendering more than once?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is it possible to call startRendering method of Web Audio API's offlineAudioContext after the AudioCompletion event?

```
var offline = new offlineAudioContext(1, 44100, 44100);
var osc = offline.createOscillator();
osc.connect(offline.destination);
offline.oncomplete = function(e){
    console.log(e);
};

offline.startRendering();

setTimeout(function(){
    offline.currentTime = 0;
    console.log(offline); //context still exists
    offline.startRendering(); // nothing happens
    osc.start(0);
}, 2000);
```

Another question is, what happens to all the nodes after the completion event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good question.  I filed this as an issue (https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/346).  I would expect no, it should only be useable once - otherwise we would need to deal with time that doesn't proceed linearly.  (Since presumably you'd want the start time to leap back to zero.)  We'd also need to clear the state of any stateful nodes (like convolvers, delays, filters).

The nodes, on the other hand - if you don't keep any references to them, I would expect they would be released and available for garbage collection, like any other JS object.